# Convert .csv file to .ods using terminal

Tags: libreoffice, convert

Is it possible convert `.csv` files to `.ods` files using command line? I have a lot archives to convert and I don't want convert them one by one.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I used the `LibreOffice` commandline to convert a sample `csv` file:

```
soffice --convert-to ods koko.csv --headless
```

So to use it in a batch command would be

```
for i in "$1"/*; do soffice --convert-to ods "$i" --headless; done
```

Usage: `./converter.sh /path/to/folder`

Comment: According to `soffice --help`, `--convert-to` implies `--headless`, so you don't need to explicitly specify it