# Adding CSV data into libreoffice-calc from cmd line

Tags: libreoffice

I want to import different .csv files into an existing libreoffice-calc document.

Each file must be inserted in a new [tab](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/s/sheet-tab.htm).

I imagine it could be written close to something like:

```
libreoffice --calc mydoc.odt import mycsv.csv@thissheet
```

which requires saving the file immediately thereafter.

But I found no example on the web, and very few API examples. Any Idea on how to proceed?

Comment: Here's how to convert one CSV file to one ODS file with the command line ('CLI'): https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105378/convert-csv-file-to-ods-using-terminal  Now we need to find how to do this with multiple CSV files and one target ODS file.

Comment: I would create a calc BASIC macro that opened all the CSV files in a directory, saved them to a separate tab and moved the CSV files into an archive directory which is later manually deleted from time to time. Then the macro exits LO. So simply from the command line you call LO telling it to run the macro.

Comment: Also posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58371507/libreoffice-calc-create-a-new-sheet-from-shell-cmd-line.

Comment: I believe --convert-to can only be used for the first sheet, so K7AAY's comment sadly will not help. @WinEunuuchs2Unix's comment is on the right track, and a call can be made from a Basic macro to a Python macro with some glue code.

Comment: @JimK Yes I have a spreadsheet that makes a hundred of bash/shell calls. The only limitation I encountered is `sudo` doesn't work.